# StatusCode.UNIMPLEMENTED when making Vertex AI API call

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have a simple Python app that invokes a Vertex AI API that fails when it runs and I can't understand why.  The application is as follows:

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1

def sample_list_datasets():
    client = aiplatform_v1.DatasetServiceClient()
    request = aiplatform_v1.ListDatasetsRequest(
        parent="projects/MYPROJECT/locations/us-central1",
    )
    page_result = client.list_datasets(request=request)
    for response in page_result:
        print(response)

sample_list_datasets()
```

when run, it fails with:

```
E0126 03:52:04.146970105   22462 hpack_parser.cc:1218]                 Error parsing metadata: error=invalid value key=content-type value=text/html; charset=UTF-8
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kolban/projects/vertex-ai/datasets/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 72, in error_remapped_callable
    return callable_(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kolban/projects/vertex-ai/datasets/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 946, in __call__
    return _end_unary_response_blocking(state, call, False, None)
  File "/home/kolban/projects/vertex-ai/datasets/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/grpc/_channel.py", line 849, in _end_unary_response_blocking
    raise _InactiveRpcError(state)
grpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
        status = StatusCode.UNIMPLEMENTED
        details = "Received http2 header with status: 404"
        debug_error_string = "UNKNOWN:Error received from peer ipv4:108.177.120.95:443 {created_time:"2023-01-26T03:52:04.147076255+00:00", grpc_status:12, grpc_message:"Received http2 header with status: 404"}"
>

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 25, in <module>
    sample_list_datasets()
  File "run.py", line 19, in sample_list_datasets
    page_result = client.list_datasets(request=request)
  File "/home/kolban/projects/vertex-ai/datasets/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/aiplatform_v1/services/dataset_service/client.py", line 1007, in list_datasets
    metadata=metadata,
  File "/home/kolban/projects/vertex-ai/datasets/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/gapic_v1/method.py", line 113, in __call__
    return wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/kolban/projects/vertex-ai/datasets/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/grpc_helpers.py", line 74, in error_remapped_callable
    raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
google.api_core.exceptions.MethodNotImplemented: 501 Received http2 header with status: 404
```

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the code to the following caused it to work:

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1
from google.api_core.client_options import ClientOptions


def sample_list_datasets():
    service_base_path='aiplatform.googleapis.com'
    region='us-central1'
    client_options = ClientOptions(api_endpoint=f"{region}-{service_base_path}")
    client = aiplatform_v1.DatasetServiceClient(client_options=client_options)
    request = aiplatform_v1.ListDatasetsRequest(
        parent="projects/MYPROJECT/locations/us-central1",
    )

    # Make the request
    page_result = client.list_datasets(request=request)

    # Handle the response
    for response in page_result:
        print(response)

sample_list_datasets()
```

The resolution was hinted at in the documentation for the API request found [here](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/aiplatform/latest/google.cloud.aiplatform_v1.services.dataset_service.DatasetServiceClient#google_cloud_aiplatform_v1_services_dataset_service_DatasetServiceClient_list_datasets).  At that article there is a code sample and in the code sample there are some comments and in the comments the following is written:

> - It may require specifying regional endpoints when creating the service
>   client as shown in:
>   https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/client_options.html

And this was the core clue.  When we make Vertex AI calls we must specify **where** the request is to be sent.  We do this by setting the `api_endpoint` option to a URL of the form `[REGION]-aiplatform.googleapis.com`.